# Declaring type table of rowtype with dynamic table

Tags: oracle, dynamic, types

I have a temporary table `TEMP_TABLE1` into which data is stored temporarily & finally merged to main table. I am using this as a common table for multiple target tables of different structure.

```
 COL1               VARCHAR2(2000)
 COL2               VARCHAR2(2000)
 COL3               VARCHAR2(2000)
 COL4               VARCHAR2(2000)
 COL5               VARCHAR2(2000)
 COL6               VARCHAR2(2000)
 COL7               VARCHAR2(2000)
 COL8               VARCHAR2(2000)
 COL9               VARCHAR2(2000)
 COL10              VARCHAR2(2000)
 COL11              VARCHAR2(2000)
 COL12              VARCHAR2(2000)
 ..
 COL40              VARCHAR2(2000)
 COL41              DATE
 COL42              DATE
```

Now i have a requirement to insert but discard some unwanted/erroneous rows. 
So i have the below working code as of now for one sample Target table.

```
declare
  type l_array is table of TEMP_TABLE3%rowtype;
       l_rec_data l_array;
       l_sql      VARCHAR2(200);
       l_start    NUMBER:=1;
       j NUMBER;
 begin
        l_sql := 'select COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5 FROM TEMP_TABLE1';
        execute immediate l_sql bulk collect into l_rec_data;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_rec_data.COUNT);
        begin 
        loop 
         begin 
          forall i in l_start .. l_rec_data.count 
          insert into TEMP_TABLE3 (COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5) values ( l_rec_data(i).COL1,l_rec_data(i).COL2,l_rec_data(i).COL3,l_rec_data(i).COL4,l_rec_data(i).COL5); 
          EXIT; 
          exception 
            when DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
            dbms_output.put_line( 'DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX row index = ' || (l_start+sql%rowcount) ||  ' ' || sqlerrm ); 
            j:=l_start+sql%rowcount;
            UPDATE TEMP_TABLE3 SET COL2=l_rec_data(j).COL2, COL3=l_rec_data(j).COL3, COL4=l_rec_data(j).COL4, COL5=l_rec_data(j).COL5 WHERE COL1=l_rec_data(j).COL1;
            l_start := l_start + 1; 
            when others then 
            dbms_output.put_line( 'Bad row index = ' || (l_start+sql%rowcount) ||  ' ' || sqlerrm ); 
            l_start := l_start + sql%rowcount + 1; 
          end; 
         end loop; 
         end;
END;
```

However, i want to declare l_array dynamically for various tables .
Ex: I might want to declare l_array as table of ( `TEMP_TABLE3%rowtype` - few rows )  Say something like below :

```
type l_array is table of TABLE(COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4)%rowtype;
```

Comment: A %ROWTYPE has to be bound to a specific table.  It can't be dynamic.  If you're determined, you could dynamically build the **entire** PL/SQL block as a string and execute that via `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.  That would be rather complicated but it could be done.  I'm not sure why your initial `SELECT` is being done via dynamic SQL here, that doesn't seem to make sense.  If `temp_table1` doesn't have exactly 5 columns, that statement will fail.  You'd just want to do a static `select *`.

Comment: Thanks , that makes sense. My initial SELECT statement is formed dynamically based on the columns i need for insert/updating target table, only the source table will be constant. My  temp_table1 has 50 predefined columns and i have a mapping for each target table in Metadata table. So i can use 5 columns for one target table while other could use 20 etc.,